# How to convert specific CURL request to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests, pycurl

I have the following Curl request:

`curl -v --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/abc' \--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \--data-raw '{data}'`

I tried using pycurl and requests command.
Also tried to put headers but it was of no use.

My tried code:

```
requests = "curl -v --location"

a = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/abc"

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url=a, headers= headers , params=data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this works?
https://curl.trillworks.com/

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{data}'

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/abc',
                         headers=headers,
                         data=data)
```

[image]

Comment: @Ashwinikumarjha If this worded fine, please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.